# JavaScript / Binding index with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code (`dbclient` is Redis client for Node.js):

```
dbclient.zrange("cache", -1000000000000000, +1000000000000000, function(err, replies) {
  logger.info("Replies: " + replies.length);
  logger.info(err);

  for (var i = 0; i < replies.length; i++) {
    logger.info("I: " + i)
    dbclient.hmget("doc:" + replies[i], "size", function(err, res) {
    cache.set(replies[i], parseInt(res[0]));
      logger.info(res[0]);
    });
  }
});
```

I notice a strange behavior:

The first output is: `Replies: 195748`, but in the `for` loop I notice that it always prints `I: 195747` and the `res[0]` is always `198536`. This run `195747` times.

It seems that it's stuck on the last index, and doesn't iterate over all items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most common errors in Javascript, in

```
function(err,res){
    cache.set(replies[i], parseInt(res[0]));
    logger.info(res[0])
}
```

you are using `i`, but that is always the one from the parent scope. Since the function is run as a callback asynchronously, it is always the value of the last loop iteration.

Change it to

```
(function(i) {
    return function(err,res){
        cache.set(replies[i], parseInt(res[0]));
        logger.info(res[0])
    };
})(i)
```

to bind `i` to the inner-most function's scope

further explanation: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: There is no need to pass `err` and `res` to the closure

Comment: You're right, I usually don't like to mix up the closures from which variables are though.

Comment: Also `i` agrument should be taken from the outer function. So it should be: `(function(i) { return function(err, res) {  /*...*/  } })(i);`